# Using `expect.any(Object)` or `expect.anything()` does not work to match `undefined` in Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have the following module which I want to test.

```
import * as apiUtils from './apiUtils';

export function awardPoints(pointsAwarding) {
  return apiUtils.callApiService("POST", "points", pointsAwarding);
}
```

And this is my test.

```
it("should call apiUtils with correct path", () => {
  //given
  jest.spyOn(apiUtils, 'callApiService');

  //when
  pointsAwardingApi.awardPoints();

  //then
  expect(apiUtils.callApiService).toBeCalledWith(expect.any(String), 'points', expect.any(Object));
});
```

When I try to run this test I get the following error.

`Any<Object> as argument 3, but it was called with undefined.`

I was expecting that `expect.any(Object)` would also match `undefined` but it seems that's not the case.

I also tried with `expect.anything()` but I get a similar error.

I could simply specify `undefined` as the third parameter but my test is only intended to verify the second parameter.

Is there a way I can use a matcher that matches any object including `undefined`?

Answer (score 15):

It looks like `expect.anything` doesn't match unset values by design. If you need a "really anything" matcher, here's one:

```js
export const expectAnythingOrNothing = expect.toBeOneOf([expect.anything(), undefined, null]);
```

You'll need `jest-extended` for the `toBeOneOf` matcher -- but it's a useful package anyway :)

Comment: This needs the `jest-extended` library

Comment: thanks @altumano, included that in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

A dumb workaround, if you just want a placeholder for an argument, could be

```js
expect.not.stringMatching('')
```

This will pass if it is an object, or `undefined`, or any string except an empty string.

**Update** This only works in <= Jest 26! For future-proofing, I wouldn't recommend this method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `expect.toSatisfy(() => true)` to get what you want (this also ships with `jest-extended`).

As for if the developer should be using this or not: when building software from scratch - probably not. But. This is a luxury most developers don't have.

Most people have to deal with untested legacy code-base and writing tests for some implementation as to provide some level of automatic validation on critical functionality when refactoring - such fuzzy argument expectations are pretty good tools to have.

Answer (score -3):

[`expect.any(constructor)`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#expectanyconstructor)  matches anything that is created with `constructor`. In your case it checks whether it has been created with the `Object` constructor, which `undefined` hasn't.

[`expect.anything()`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#expectanything) matches anything but `null` and `undefined`, because both of these are considered *nothing* in JavaScript. `expect.anything()` is a shortcut for testing that it's neither `null` nor `undefined`.

What you're trying to test is not *anything*, but rather *I don't care what it is or if it even exists*. There is no matcher for such a thing and there shouldn't be one, because if you don't care what it is, you don't test it.

> I could simply specify undefined as the third parameter but my test is only intended to verify the second parameter.

I honestly think that testing a specific parameter to a function call is not a good approach. Why would you have to test only this argument for the function? In general a function only provides meaningful output if all arguments were given and if you have optional arguments you still specifically test that they were missing.

If the argument is computed in some complex way, you should test the computation instead, which might require you to refactor it out of the current function.

Comment: I want my test to check only one thing. I want my test to just check the path I'm sending in the second parameter is correct no matter what arguments I send to `awardPoints()`. I would write a different unit test for each parameter.

Comment: Testing each parameter means to me that you want to test some complex code that creates that value. In the end you are not testing that the function is called correctly, but that the value for one parameter has been computed correctly. So it should be a standalone function which you test on its own. If it's not complex enough that you think it should be its own function, then you might be over-testing it, as you might even be testing language features instead of the logic in your application.